# Pytest Flask Application AttributeError: module 'src.api' has no attribute 'test_client'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pytest

I am trying a basic Pytest test for a "hello world" flask application
Please see below what I have in the src file

**api.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify


api = Flask(__name__)


@api.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return jsonify(message="hello world")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    api.run(debug=True)
```

and this is what I have written for the test

**test_api.py**

```
import pytest
from src import api


api.testing = True
client = api.test_client()


def test_route(client):
    response = api.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

**Structure**

```
my_project
    __init__.py
    src
        __init__.py
        api.py
    test
        __init__.py
        test_api.py
```

I run the tests from the root with `python -m pytest`

The error message I get is

```
test/test_api.py:13: in <module>
    with api.test_client() as client:
E   AttributeError: module 'src.api' has no attribute 'test_client'
```

I am really unsure of how to make this work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`from src import api` imports the module of `src/api.py`

However, you are interested in the global `api` object that is within the scope of that `src.api` module

`from src.api import api` will import the flask application object which should have the `test_client` method that you are calling.